# Как проверить доступность порта по udp?

Tags: centos, udp

Необходимо проверить доступность порта на удаленном хосте. Пробовал использовать netcat:

```
nc -vzu xx.xx.xx.xx *port*
```

Но вывод не особо понятен. Я не уверен, что эта утилита подходит для этого. Есть ли вообще возможность увидеть, что порт в полном порядке и нет никаких проблем с доступностью?

Comment: Единственная возможность — получить от удалённого хоста ответ на свой запрос. Если он отвечает, значит порт явно доступен, а если нет, то это может значить что угодно, от реального отсутствия доступности и до того, что хост на вас просто обиделся и не хочет отвечать.

Comment: При использовании netcat он только показывает, что отправил один пакет, но ничего не принял. При этом там есть опция, которая позволяет только принимать пакет, но не отправлять, но даже с ней утилита только отправляет его. При этом сам порт доступен, так как нужные скрипты/программы обращаются к нему